# How would i rename a list item in an array?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

Basically, im trying to be able to rename a list item from an array list. The typical `arrayList.set(index, "something")` doesn't help a lot in my case as i'm using a class like this...

```
public class Song {

private long id;
private String title;
private String artist;

public Song(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist) {
    id=songID;
    title=songTitle;
    artist=songArtist;
}

public long getID(){return id;}
public String getTitle(){return title;}
public String getArtist(){return artist;}
```

}

So i'm guessing the second parameter of the `arrayList.set` method has to be associated with this class, and i'm unsure as to how i would do this. For example, if i wanted to change the title, would i use something like `arrayList.set(index, Song(null, newTitle, null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `setter` to your object:

```
class Song {

    // ...

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist){
        this.artist = artist;
    }
}
```

And then use the `get(int index)` method of the array to find the Song to rename.

```
arrayList.get(index).setTitle("new Title");
```

> Doing `arrayList.set(index, Song(null, newTitle, null)` won't rename the existing song already present in the array at the index. This will create a new Song and replace the one store at the given index.

And BTW `new Song(null, newTitle, null)` won't compile because your `id`cannot be `null`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working. However, it seems to reset itself after i restart the app...

Comment: This depends on how you are saving your datas what kind of persistance are you using?

Comment: I updated my post with the method that retrieves the song info.

Comment: Then the "reset" is normal what you are doing rename just the Song into you array. All this has no impact on the titles of the song provided by the ` ContentResolver`.

Comment: Ah, so how would i rename the song directly from the content resolver? Or is that a different question entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know... may be you can ask a new question on SO for this.